# InnoDB: ALTER TABLE performance related to NULLability?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've got a table with 10M rows, and I'm trying to `ALTER TABLE` to add another column (a `VARCHAR(80)`).

From a data-modelling perspective, that column should be `NOT NULL` - but the amount of time it takes to run the statement is a consideration, and the client code could be changed to deal with a `NULL` column if that's warranted.

Should the `NULL`-ability of the column I'm trying to add significantly impact the amount of time it takes to add the column either way?

**More Information**

The context in which I'm doing this is a Django app, with a migration generated by South - adding three separate columns, and adding an index on one of the newly-added columns. Looking at the South-generated SQL, it spreads this operation (adding three columns and an index) over 15 `ALTER TABLE` statements - which seems like it will make this operation take a whole lot longer than it should.

I've seen some references that suggest that InnoDB doesn't actually have to create a field in the on-disk file for nullable fields that are `NULL`, and just modifies a bitfield in the header. Would this impact the speed of the `ALTER TABLE` operation?

Comment: I just tried it on my database with 80k rows(16 columns), and it seemed to be done in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the nullability of the column has anything to do with the speed of `ALTER TABLE`. In most alter table operations, the whole table - with all the indexes - has to be copied (temporarily) and then the alteration is done on the copy. With 10M rows, it's kind of slow. From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> Storage, Performance, and Concurrency Considerations
>
> In most cases, **`ALTER TABLE` makes a temporary copy of the original table**. MySQL waits for other operations that are modifying the table, then proceeds. It incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes the original table, and renames the new one. While `ALTER TABLE` is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions. Updates and writes to the table that begin after the `ALTER TABLE` operation begins are stalled until the new table is ready, then are automatically redirected to the new table without any failed updates. The temporary table is created in the database directory of the new table. This can differ from the database directory of the original table for `ALTER TABLE` operations that rename the table to a different database.

---

If you want to make several changes in a table's structure, it's usually better to do them in one `ALTER TABLE` operation.

---

Allowing client code to make changes in tables is probably not the best idea - and you have hit on one good reason for not allowing that. Why do you need it? If you can't do otherwise, it would probably be better - for performance reasons - to allow your client code to be creating a table (with the new column and the PK of the existing table) instead of adding a column.

Comment: To clarify, a NOT NULL column will be filled with the default value. If you've not specified a default value, then the default for that type will be used.